# In C++, whether a derived object can first construct derived part then construct base part?

Tags: c++

As we know, In C++, if a derived `class B: public A {}`, derives from its base class `A`.
When we call class `B`'s constructor to generate an instance of `B`, we have to first call base `A`'s constructor and then initialize derived part.
So why we couldn't swap the sequence, i.e.first initialize derived part then call base's constructor? If do so, what problem will it lead to?

Comment: Why would you like to swap the sequence? Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: yeah, it is a question from a case interview.

Comment: When constructing an instance of a derived class, the standard is quite specific in specifying the order in which constructors of bases are called, and that the constructor of the most derived class is called after constructors of all its bases.

Comment: There are so many things in C++ which are declared as Undefined Behavior by the standard. Actually, I always enjoy to know that certain things are strictly defined in C++ (so that you can rely on this), and the initialization order of a class (concerning base classes and members) is one of them... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

> So why we couldn't swap the sequence, i.e.first initialize derived part then call base's constructor? If do so, what problem will it lead to?

That way the derived class contructor wouldn't be able to use the base sub object. That would be an unnecessary limitation.

Comment: or from the other perspective: A base doesn't know about its derived classes, hence it cannot use the derived class. On the other hand, the derived does know its base and can use it

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that there is room to play with the strict order concerning the construction of classes.

Say, we have to following intention to implement:

- a base class which reads something from an arbitrary stream object
- a derived class specialized to do so for a file stream.

This is how the base class could look like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Reader {
  // stream to read from
  std::istream& in;

  // constructor.
  Reader(std::istream& in): in(in) { }

  // intentionally not available (would break RAII)
  Reader(const Reader&) = delete;

  // read function
  void read();

};
```

A derived class for convenient reading of files:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Reader.h"

struct FileReader: Reader {

  // file stream to read from
  std::ifstream fIn;

  // constructor
  FileReader(const std::string& filePath);

};
```

So, here we are: We have to initialize `fIn` before constructing the base class `Reader`.

This is in fact a simplified real-world problem I once faced in my daily business, and I came up with the following solution:

I introduced yet another base class:

```
struct FStream {
  std::ifstream fIn;
  FStream(const std::string& filePath): fIn(filePath) { }
};

struct FileReader: FStream, Reader {

  // constructor
  FileReader(const std::string& filePath):
    FStream(filePath),
    Reader(FStream::fIn)
  { }

};
```

Relying on the defined order how base classes and members are initialized (in the strict order how declared i.e. from left to right and top to down), this opens the file stream `fIn` before the base class `Reader` is initialized with the reference to `fIn`.

A complete [**MCVE on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2edd6bb5c887eee9) to demonstrate this in action:

```
// Reader.h:

#include <iostream>

struct Reader {
  // stream to read from
  std::istream& in;

  // constructor.
  Reader(std::istream& in): in(in) { }

  // intentionally not available (would break RAII)
  Reader(const Reader&) = delete;

  // read function
  void read();

};

// Reader.cc:

#include <string>

//#include "Reader.h"

void Reader::read()
{
  for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line);) std::cout << "Read: " << line << '\n';
}

// FileReader.h:

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//#include "Reader.h"

struct FStream {
  std::ifstream fIn;
  FStream(const std::string& filePath): fIn(filePath) { }
};

struct FileReader: FStream, Reader {

  // constructor
  FileReader(const std::string& filePath):
    FStream(filePath),
    Reader(FStream::fIn)
  { }

};

// main.cpp:

//#include "FileReader.h"

int main()
{
  FileReader reader("./main.cpp");
  reader.read();
}
```

Output:

```
Read: // Reader.h:
Read: 
Read: #include <iostream>
Read: 
Read: struct Reader {
Read:   // stream to read from
Read:   std::istream& in;
Read: 
Read:   // constructor.
Read:   Reader(std::istream& in): in(in) { }
Read: 
Read:   // intentionally not available (would break RAII)
Read:   Reader(const Reader&) = delete;
Read: 
Read:   // read function
Read:   void read();
Read: 
Read: };
Read: 
Read: // Reader.cc:
Read: 
Read: #include <string>
Read: 
Read: //#include "Reader.h"
Read: 
Read: void Reader::read()
Read: {
Read:   for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line);) std::cout << "Read: " << line << '\n';
Read: }
Read: 
Read: // FileReader.h:
Read: 
Read: #include <fstream>
Read: #include <string>
Read: //#include "Reader.h"
Read: 
Read: struct FStream {
Read:   std::ifstream fIn;
Read:   FStream(const std::string& filePath): fIn(filePath) { }
Read: };
Read: 
Read: struct FileReader: FStream, Reader {
Read: 
Read:   // constructor
Read:   FileReader(const std::string& filePath):
Read:     FStream(filePath),
Read:     Reader(FStream::fIn)
Read:   { }
Read: 
Read: };
Read: 
Read: // main.cpp:
Read: 
Read: //#include "FileReader.h"
Read: 
Read: int main()
Read: {
Read:   FileReader reader("./main.cpp");
Read:   reader.read();
Read: }
```